# Scala REPL - Display of List[String]

Tags: scala

How do I get the Scala REPL to display a List[String] with quotes around the string items ?

For example, if I define

```
scala>  val colorPairs = List("red, green", "yellow, blue")
colorPairs: List[String] = List(red, green, yellow, blue)
```

What gets shown are the strings without quotes, making it appear as though
there are 4 string items above instead of 2. How can I remedy this ?

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of this (unsatisfactorily answered) question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7851259/1240268

Comment: No doubt it's just a matter of time. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8603

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that's configurable in the scala REPL, but you could try [Ammonite](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#Ammonite).

```scala
@ val colorPairs = List("red, green", "yellow, blue")
colorPairs: List[String] = List("red, green", "yellow, blue")
```

Comment: Awesome! The scala repl sucks. (and it's got color, and works with sbt)

Answer (score 2):

The `toString` method of `List` produces the representation without quotes:

```
scala> val colorPairs = List("red, green", "yellow, blue")
colorPairs: List[String] = List(red, green, yellow, blue)

scala> colorPairs.toString
res0: String = List(red, green, yellow, blue)
```

This is implemented in [TraversableLike](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L1):

```
  /** Converts this $coll to a string.
   *
   *  @return   a string representation of this collection. By default this
   *            string consists of the `stringPrefix` of this $coll, followed
   *            by all elements separated by commas and enclosed in parentheses.
   */
  override def toString = mkString(stringPrefix + "(", ", ", ")")
```

**(Update thanks to som-snytt)** However, ScalaRunTime provides various special case rendering, for example:

```
scala> List("")
res3: List[java.lang.String] = List("")

scala> List("1")
res4: List[java.lang.String] = List(1)

scala> List(" 1 ")
res6: List[java.lang.String] = List(" 1 ")
```

which is due to the following `case`s:

```
case ""       => "\"\""
case x:String => if (x.head.isWhitespace || x.last.isWhitespace) "\"" + x + "\"" else x
```

There are various ways of showing the list contents more accurately, of course:

```
scala> colorPairs foreach println
red, green
yellow, blue

scala> colorPairs.map("\"" + _ + "\"")
res2: List[String] = List("red, green", "yellow, blue")
```

Or you could enrich List and similar collections with a new method for this:

```
implicit class TLWrapper(t: TraversableLike[String,_]){
     def show = t.mkString(t.stringPrefix + "(\"", "\", \"", "\")")
}

scala> List("red, green","yellow, blue").show
res10: String = List("red, green", "yellow, blue")
```

Comment: This works, but only for the specific case of List[String] (and not in the REPL).

Comment: It also works for any other `TraversableLike` (such as `Vector` or `Set`) but I agree it's not very convenient for the REPL.

Comment: This is mostly true, but it was a conscious design decision at some point. Consider `List("      a     ")`, where quotes are injected to show the padding. It's the work of `scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf`.

Comment: @som-snytt Thanks! - Have updated answer to take ScalaRunTime into account