# What is Java function equivalent to Ruby Object#inspect

Tags: java, ruby

In Ruby I can get instance variable val with following code

```ruby
class C
  def initialize(*args, &blk)
    @iv = "iv"
    @iv2 = "iv2"
  end
end

puts "C.new.inspect:#{C.new.inspect} ---- #{::File.basename __FILE__}:#{__LINE__}"
# => C.new.inspect:#<C:0x4bbfb90a @iv="iv", @iv2="iv2"> ---- ex.rb:8
```

In Java, I expect I can get following result, how should I do?

```java
package ro.ex;

public class Ex {
    String attr;
    String attr2;

    public Ex() {
        this.attr = "attr";
        this.attr2 = "attr2";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ex().inspect();
        // => Ex attr= "attr", attr2 = "attr2";
    }
}
```

update:

i find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333974/how-to-loop-over-a-class-attributes-in-java) can solve my question, but i wanna more simple, like some function in guava.in ruby, i primarily use Object#inspect in rubymine watch tool window, i expect i can use it like obj.inspect

update:

i finally determine use Tedy Kanjirathinkal answer and i implement by myself with following code:

```
package ro.ex;

import com.google.common.base.Functions;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by roroco on 10/23/14.
 */
public class Ex {
    String attr;
    String attr2;

    public Ex() {
        this.attr = "val";
        this.attr2 = "val2";
    }

    public String inspect() {
        Field[] fs = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        String r = getClass().getName();
        for (Field f : fs) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            String val = null;
            try {
                r = r + " " + f.getName() + "=" + f.get(this).toString();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackTraceElement traces = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0];
        System.out.println(new Ex().inspect());
        // => ro.ex.Ex attr=val attr2=val2
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you put that (e.g., the code in the link) into a function?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350397/java-equivalent-of-python-repr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you want is [ReflectionToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html) in [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) library.

In your class, define your inspect() method like as follows, and you should be able to see the expected result:

```
public void inspect() {
    System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most common method is to override toString on the class to output whatever the internal state of the class is, and then use it with `System.out.println`. If you want to do something more automatic, then look up how reflection or introspection can help you. Try `BeanUtils`.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent method is [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), although this gives a useless unreadable jumble unless overriden.